# error when compiling telegram cli with cygwin

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin, telegram

I followed the instruction in [this](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/blob/master/README-Cygwin.md) page, but "cd tg && ./configure" command throws the following errors:

```
./configure: line 14: $'\r': command not found
./configure: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
'/configure: line 29: `     ;;
```

no idea where should I look for the problem.

Comment: Possibly, the configure script has MS-DOS-style line endings (<CR><LF>), but the shell that is executing the script is expecting Unix-style line endings (<LF> only).

Comment: I agree with Ian. Use `d2u configure` to convert to Unix-style

Comment: @ian-abbot , matzeri thank you for your guidance, but it shows these errors when converting! :
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x07 found at line 7653
dos2unix: Skipping binary file configure

Comment: @matzeri i also checked the encoding of file and it was :  us-ascii

Comment: 0x07 is the bell character. looks on line 7653 and see if you can convert it to an escape sequence

Comment: The style of line endings doesn't really affect the the encoding, as both <CR> and <LF> are us-ascii characters. If you are still struggling with the conversion, many programmer-oriented text editors support loading and saving with different line endings.